# Logcat doesn't show & phone crashes

Tags: android, google-play-services

So, I am using Android Studio vor developing an android app.

The first problem is that when I debug the app on the phone and it crashes (no matter what the reason is) i don't get an error message, i get a frozen phone that doesn't work and i have to force-restart it. Any idea why that is happening?

Second problem is that logcat doesn't show anything in the logs while i debug on the phone so I don't know what exactly caused the crash.

On the emulator i have no crashes, but i don't have Google Play Services there either (that's what i want to test and i think causes the unknown crash).

Thx

Comment: surround your code with try catch block and then see exception if get any.

Comment: Have you tried to set as launcher another activity (that you are sure that has nothing to crash for, also put a Log there to see what happens) that redirect to your current activity(that crashes),because sometimes happens that logcat doesnt show anything if main launch activity isnt launched

Comment: @wqrahd, tried to wrap the whole thing in a try catch, nothing caught though.

Comment: @Ultimo_m, the activity launches, it waits for a couple of seconds and then it crashes.

Both the phone crash and the logcat logs not showing when debugging on phone are are problems since before the app crash problem, just that it didn't disturb me so far :P

Comment: post your code please.so we examine what could be the root of your problem.

Comment: Still, my problem isn't exactly on the code, it's more on the issue that logcat doesn't show and the phone crashes when ANY app crashes, not just mine.